# Property executeChildBindings not found on s:Application

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, graniteds

I changed from mx:Application to s:Application in the GraniteDS examples. When i deploy and run the project in JBoss 5 I get the error as ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property executeChildBindings not found on [SwfName].
I am building all the JARs and SWFs for Granite from source. One of the class Tide.as has the offending line

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.executeChildBindings(true);
```

So what is the equivqlent for a s:Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can user executeBindings() method. 
More information is available here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_2.html